# K8s for fintech apps

Tags: kubernetes

I’m planning to expand my expense management app to integrate with credit cards. There is a third party service that manages card issuing and transactions and id like to build an app for customers to show transactions and make payments.

I believe I don’t need to host in k8s because

1. It’s ok to have downtime, preferably during midnights for server updates. Customers are not going to be online 24 x 7 just like social media.
2. US only customers and not spanning the whole world. Load balance is not fully necessary.
3. Scaling up or down isn’t important either because the number of customers is fairly less. Even if we ramp up to 1000s of customers in the future, the number of transactions (check balance or make/update payments) are going to be low unlike social media.

I’ve highlighted my opinion above and planned to host it on ec2, probably two instances on both coasts with a load balancer (to avoid single point of failure). Given the above info, I’ll need some advice since k8s is not cost efficient compared to individual instances.